# Wordpress returns no content for certain admin pages like post.php

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site that was running fine with version 5.7.2.  Everything was working as expected (as far as I know).  Today I upgraded to 5.8 (using the onclick upgrade within wordpress itself).  Since then the post.php simply does nothing, it just closes the connection whenever you go to it (this is also the same for post-new.php, uploads.php, user-edit.php user-new.php but not users.php ).  I cant find any errors in the apache logs (and I have the error recording turned on in the php.ini, and there is no output in the wordpress debug.log despite having the following settings:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

in the wp-config.php.

The site itself appears to work as expected, all of the pages and plugins work.  I have used the Health Check & Troubleshooting plugin to run the site with all the plugins and themes disabled and this does not address the issue.  The issue is not tied to a single client as I can login on different devices and I get the same error.

The error is not just on post.php, but can also be seen by visiting certain admin pages, for example the yoast plugin, whenever try to use the admin pages you get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more digging I found the following error in the apache error logs (not the one specific to my vhost)

```
double free or corruption (out)
free(): invalid next size (fast)
free(): invalid next size (fast)
[Sun Sep 05 22:38:50.226213 2021] [core:notice] [pid 53059] AH00052: child pid 53063 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

This error would appear any time you load one of the effected pages.

On doing more research I found from here https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/622 that having both the php modules for graphicsmagick and imagemagick would cause this memory error.  I removed graphicsmagick and everyhing works again.